# ¿Como manejar un refresh oken desde el frontend?

Tags: angular, jwt, rxjs, refreshtoken

espero me puedan ayudar con esta pegrunta estoy tratando de entender un poco este concepto de trabajar con un refresh token. Pero desde la perspectiva del frontend, no se bien como manejarlo.

Actualmente lo estoy trabajando con angular. y con un interceptor pongo el token normal en las cabeceras pero no se como hacer la actualizacion de un nuevo token con el refresh token sin interrumpir el flujo de trabajo del usuario.

Porque por ejemplo, yo he pensado en una peticion al servidor (que tambien he creado yo), entonces si digamos me devuelve un 401 unhatorized es porque el token ya caduco, con respuesta, hago una nueva peticion al enpoind de el servidor que recibe un refresh token y devuelve uno nuevo y lo guardo, pero no se como hacer con la peticion original que hizo el usuario porque en en ese punto ya la interrumpi por generar el neuvo token.  No se como se debe manejar estos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso lo mejor sería trabajarlo en tu session storage o local storage, entonces lo que deberias hacer es obtener el token desde el localstorage e ir actualizando ese dato